# Live Internet Based Data Transfer

Tags: java, android, messaging

*I'm currently searching for a way to transfer a String array from one android to another through the internet (assuming both devices are connected to the internet).*

There's the possibility that one (or both) of the devices is connected to a network which is provided by a router, therefore using the IP address isn't practical (as far as I know).

I've stumbled upon an idea which suggests using Email to transfer the data. but, if I'm not wrong, that will force me to translate the array to an Email, send it, and undo the translation (to get it back to a string array form).

I would prefer a solution that will transfer the String array as it is.

Is it possible? Is there a better way to executed this process?

(I'm developing in Java on the Eclipse IDE)

I'd be glad to hear your Ideas! (:

Comment: Im assuming both users would have this app installed?

Comment: the information you provide is way too inaccurate... try to give more details about what you actually do

Comment: -your assumption is correct.  
..
-what I actually do? Both of the devices are supposed to send a String array to each other, and then the arrays goes through some kind of a process. The idea I'm looking for is how to transfer the String array as a String array through the internet....  

if that's not what you meant, can you please be more specific on the details that you think are missing?  

Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

1. Device A sends an HTTP Request to the web server, Device B regularly gets data( using timer ) by sending request to fetch message sent to him. But this is not really real-time.
2. Device A sends an HTTP Request to the web server, The Server Pushs to Device B. You need to implement Push using Comet or GWT.[Comet wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
3. Implement XMPP Messaging. Device A send an XMPP Request, Server push to Device B. [XMPP wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)

If I were you, I will do no 3. Since your explanation sounds more related to real-time messaging case. Please forget thinking about using email.

Comment: this had been very educating for me!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Which Client should I choose? or how can I be sure it will work on an android device?     also if you know  a source that integrates Java and XMPP Messaging I'd be glad to read it!         
thanks in advance

Comment: For android devices, you can use Smack(XMPP library for java) and for server you can use OpenFire. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfire The smack library and the Open Fire library can be found in http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp